# Check if string exists in meta key string using meta_query check in wordpress get_posts function

Tags: php, wordpress

OK you would think this is a fairly trivial piece of code, but it is not working.

The code below is not broken, it is just not working as it should.

---

Ok, in wordpress I have a custom field in my custom post-type: **individual**, this custom field has a meta_key of: **login_email**

The contents of this meta_key is simply email addresses.

Here are some examples of the contents..

```
bob.dougal@gmail.com, bob.dougal@company.com, bob.dougal@hotmail.com
```

or..

```
bob.dougal@gmail.com, bob.dougal@hotmail.com
```

or even just a single email string..

```
bob.dougal@hotmail.com
```

---

OK, so now you seen the string contents of the custom field. I can explain what I am trying to achieve.

I have this variable... `$current_user_email = $current_user->user_login;`

Which is a single email address string.

I then need to find if this email address exists within the meta_key contents. So this how I've done it...

```
$lastposts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'post_type'         => 'individual',
    'post_status'       => 'private',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'login_email',
            'value' => $current_user_email,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
));
```

In my example above, if I echo `$current_user_email` it outputs `bob.dougal@company.com`

But even though bob.dougal@company.com exists in one of the custom fields like this... `bob.dougal@gmail.com, bob.dougal@company.com, bob.dougal@hotmail.com`, my get_post returns nothing.

If I then go to the post editor and remove all the other emails from the custom field so `bob.dougal@company.com` is the only text in the custom field, then the above query works!

My question is, how can I get meta_query to find `bob.dougal@company.com` within a meta_key which contains this string: `bob.dougal@gmail.com, bob.dougal@company.com, bob.dougal@hotmail.com`

Because '**IN**' is not doing what it is meant to.

Code taken from http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Thanks

Comment: If you have say three email addresses, how are you adding them? As one single meta field that contains all three addresses (literally `bob.dougal@gmail.com, bob.dougal@company.com, bob.dougal@hotmail.com`), or as three separate meta fields each containing one email address? If it's the first option, replace `IN` with `LIKE`.

Comment: Yes - LIKE worked thanks!!! Yeah one meta containing just that as a string (not an array)

Comment: Happy to help. I've added this as an answer and would be grateful if you would accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this may be happening because you are storing multiple email addresses in one key, as opposed to having multiple keys with one email address each.

Because of this, `IN` will not work as it checks if a given value exists within a set of possibilities (similar to how the PHP `in_array()` works).

What you need to do is replace `IN` with `LIKE`. This will check the whole string for occurrences of your email address and return matches.

You should be careful though, as this can lead to inconstant results. For example, if `$current_user_email = bob.dougal@company.com;` then all of the following will be true -

```
bob.dougal@gmail.com, 1bob.dougal@company.com, bob.dougal@hotmail.com
bob.dougal@gmail.com, 12bob.dougal@company.com, bob.dougal@hotmail.com
bob.dougal@gmail.com, 123bob.dougal@company.com, bob.dougal@hotmail.com
```

I'll grant you that it is unlikely, but that's why you should not use strings to store multiple values. I'd strongly suggest using multiple keys (you can have many with the same name) and then you can use `IN` in your query. This would also guarentee only exact matches.

Comment: That is a very good point about the occurrences - but for my small project this is very unlikely so is a quick fix. Thanks

Comment: Agreed in this case, but it's good to know for the future. No doubt the next project will start as soon as your current one has finished!

Answer (score 1):

$current_user_email is a string. So transform this string into an array:

```
$current_user_email = explode(", ", $current_user_email);

$lastposts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'individual',
    'post_status' => 'private',
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
             'key' => 'login_email',
             'value' => $current_user_email,
             'compare' => 'IN'
         )
    )
));
```